# Validate special character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to validate in special character like `@, #, $, %, ^, &, *` in Javascript and show the message to the user. If user input the combination of these special character, I need to show a message and prevent from save the form.

I tried the below one:

```
var label_name = $('#label_name_popup').val();
var regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/
if (!regExp.test(label_name)) {
    alert("Special character not allowed")
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
    
}
```

This is not working. Can any one help me how to validate it in Javascript?

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: How is it not working? It doesn't look like your problem comes from the code snippet you've posted here...

Comment: @JeremyThille Always goes to else part and getting saved

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the label_name value. I just put it in a fiddle and put manual values in label_name variable and works fine.

Comment: What are the inputs that you tried?

Comment: Your regex test seems to be working [(codepen)](http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/zZdozy). I guess the problem lies around this code block.

Comment: Try trimming the value string before testing.

Comment: @JeremyThille I trimmed the space and it is working now. And i want to allow _ also. How to include it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `keyup` event to test the `input` value with every newly typed character. If it doesn't pass the test function, alert will appear.

*That doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work.* - OP didn't drop his code in any function nor didn't bind it to any `event listener`. So how was it supposed to work then?

*prevent from save the form.* - you can implement a `boolean` variable holding a `truthy` value if the input is valid or `falsy` if it's not.

Then implement a simple condition, while submitting the form, that while the `isInputValid` variable is false, the form can't be submitted.

```js
var regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/),
    isInputValid = false;

$('#label_name_popup').on('keyup', function() {
  var label_name = $('#label_name_popup').val();
  if (regExp.test(label_name) && label_name) {
    console.log("The form is valid.");
    isInputValid = true;
  } else {
    console.log("The form is invalid.");
    isInputValid = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='label_name_popup'>
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work. This is the same Regex test. Besides, it alerts that the character is not allowed, but allows it nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, it's much better this way :)